# Can't debug with Symfony CLI / Xdebug

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, symfony5

I am running my server with `symfony server:start` command and I would like to debug it as usual with PHP remote debug provided by PhpStorm.

I've configured my Xdebug with these:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

I have installed the debugtool for my browser and configured my server in the PHP remote debug window.

When I'm trying to debug my IDE is breaking in the router at `/myuser/.symfony/php/3769648aac6303b385b2ccc41cfd442044060c7d-router.php:12` and saying it's outside the project.

I also tried path mappings with no results.

**If you need more Information please let me know.**

Comment: 1) Where your project is located on your computer (the path to the project root)? I do not think it will be in `/myuser/.symfony/php/` folder .. so the "outside of the project" message will be correct here. 2) That path, it looks like a PHP temp folder or alike and that `3769648aac6303b385b2ccc41cfd442044060c7d-router.php` file is auto-generated (Symfony optimisation/compilation).

Comment: 3) You can tell PhpStorm to ignore files that are outside of the project -- disable `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug | Xdebug | Force break at first line when a script is outside the project` option for that.

Comment: P.S. Your desrciption is not super clear for me right now: on one hand I see that you are running your web server with `symfony server:start` command (that suggests that it's a local execution (the same OS/host)). Then you are mentioning "php remote debug" few times ... that suggests otherwise (that it's a remote debug .. and perhaps path mappings is the issue here). You better clarify your setup as much as possible, with screenshots (they help a lot)

Comment: In either case, check these links: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html

Comment: @LazyOne 1) My project is in ```/Documents/dev/myproject``` and that's breaking in my Symfony CLI installed in my computer.

Comment: 2-3) I disabled the break at the first line option and installed PHP-FPM and it's now working with the same configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running with PHP 7.4 CLI i tried to install the latest version of PHP-FPM and it's now working with the same configuration as above.

I also disabled the option `the Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug | Xdebug | Force break at first line when a script is outside the project` as @LazyOne said, thanks to him.

Answer (score 0):

I still have this problem. Every debug request ends up with the intellij popping up with an incoming request approval for the router file `/home/user/.symfony/php/xxxx-router.php`, and after `[ Accept ]` nothing happens and the actual breakpoint is ignored.

The setting "`Force break at first line when a script is outside the project`" is disabled.

It's php 8.1, with xdebug 3.1.5,`symfony server:start`

[image: Incoming Connection From Xdebug]

Also adding the symfony server path to the skipped paths doesnt really help.
[image: Skipped Paths]

The Xdebug settings:

[image: Xdebug ini]

What else can be checked?

Answer (score 0):

Another important notice - you need to disable "Ignore external connectsion" OR PhpStorm will ignore debug connection[image]